# How do I access resource files in Java (Intellij)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, resources, project-structure

I can't seem to get my head around accessing resource files, when the resources-marked folder 'resources' is not inside the source-marked folder 'java'.

Here is my project structure (which follows Maven structure, but I still like it):

```
|src 
|-main
|--java (marked as sources folder)
|--|projectname
|--|-main.java
|--|-Class2.java
|--|- ..
|--|-Classx.java
|--resources (marked as resources folder)
|--|config.properties
|--|images
```

[this is how it looks in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PDwj.png)

I have applied every possible change to the following line, still I can't seem to load the config.properties file or any other file from the resources folder.

```
getClass().getResource("config.properties");
```

which is being called in the main class.
This should be working right? Why doesn't it though?

How do I access a resource with this project structure?

Much love, Jiefu

edit 1:
after same testing, it seems to have to do with directories being between the marked source folder and the content root (which is parent of src here)
I don't yet know why this is or how to get around it...

Solved:
turns out, deleting the output folder and restarting IntelliJ fixes it. I had to do it twice though...
Weird.

I was wrapping my head for two days about this and this is what it was ^.^

Answer (score 3):

Your class is in package `projectname`, so the code is looking for the resource file `projectname/config.properties`, but the file is not there.

To look for resource file `config.properties`, use:

```
getClass().getResource("/config.properties");
```

as **documented** in the javadoc of [`getResource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-).

And remember, the resource may not be a file on the file system, so don't use e.g. `File` to access it. To read the content of the resource, use [`getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) instead.

Comment: still, simply testing it with System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/config.properties")) gives me null as output.
I have read a lot about what I am doing wrong and I am very glad that you confirm that this is the way it should be done.
Unfortunately it doesn't work...